# PyMySQL insert not working

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host = '127.0.0.1', unix_socket = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
                       user = 'root', passwd='', db = 'mysql')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("USE info")

def store(name, review_url, city, state, zip, phone_number, rooms, email):

    # prints this
    print('trying to commit')

    sql = "INSERT INTO 'Hotels' ('name', 'review_url', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone_number', 'rooms', 'email') VALUES" \
          "(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    cur.execute(sql, (name, review_url, city, state, zip, phone_number, rooms, email))
    cur.connection.commit() 

    # doesnt print this
    print('tried to commit')
```

I'm not getting any errors, the database name and the table name are correct as well as all the column names.

It prints out 'trying to commit' but it doesnt print out 'tried to commit'

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Isn't it just conn.commit()?

Comment: @Dan-Dev I think either way works, I changed it to conn.commit() and receiving the same behavior

Comment: Think to give an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My server give this error : `(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Hotels' ('name', 'review_url', 'city', 'state', [ … ]  at line 1")`. This looks like to be a quote related problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have single quotes around

```
"INSERT INTO 'Hotels' ('name', 'review_url', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone_number', 'rooms', 'email')
```

Try using no single quotes or use backticks

```
"INSERT INTO Hotels (name, review_url, city, state, zip, phone_number, rooms, email)
```